# FluentValidation Asp.net MVC + Return Messages with hpyperlink in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I am using fluent validation for asp.net mvc, and I am wondering if it is possible to return a message that has html code in it such as a hyperlink?

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property).NotEmpty().WithMessage("<a href="test.com">Go Here</a>");
```

this does not render the anchor tag as html but as plan text.

I tried to also do this

```
@Html.Raw(ValidationSummary(false, "", new {@class ="callout"});
```

but still same problem.